# Converting an image or still picture on an iPhone/android to a 5 sec video using Livecode

Tags: ios, livecode

I am using Livecode on a Mac with MergAV enabled.  I would like to be able to do two things.
1) Take a still image from the Camera Roll and covert it to Video. (A 5 sec clip)
and
2) Be able to capture a portion of the iPad screen of my App and covert it to a 5 sec clip.

Thank you!

Comment: So far you have posted what you want to do. YOu need to post an actual question. Update your question with what you have tried and what you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here.

- The subject says iPhone/android and mergAV only supports iOS and OS X so we won't be able to get this working on android any time soon.
- The second issue which applies to both #1 and #2 is mergAV doesn't yet support creating a video from an image. It's possible to implement it though so if you want to discuss that please contact me via mergExt.com.

Comment: Hi there!  I tried to contact you via mergExt.com and it kept bringing me back here. I would really like to learn how to use Livecode and mergAV to convert still images on an iPhone to video via mergExt and Livecode.  Thanks for your help!  jrarick@hpsk12.net